# Where is Job’s attitude towards God in Chapter 12 coming from?

Tags: job, attributes-of-god

Job has a scathing description of God in chapter 12, including

> He makes priests walk barefoot and overthrows the secure ones. He deprives the trusted ones of speech and takes away the discernment of the elders. (Verses 19-20). NASB

Where is this view of God deliberately misleading His people and making them wander in darkness (v.25) coming from? Is it something Job has personally seen God do, or a cry of frustration due to his current circumstances that is not tied to reality?

Comment: What Bible version have you quoted - I cannot find one that says this.

Comment: The term 'kohen' is proven in one case to refer to a non-Levite(2Sa 8:18/1Ch 18:17, cmp. also 2Ch 26:18-21).

Comment: @Dottard I apologize, I was quoting from a translation by Hebrew Scholar Robert Alter which is known to be one that is very true to the original but also not widely available - I edited to quote from the NASB version.

Comment: No problem with quoting such a version, just name the unusual source.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of Job / Iyov (אִיּ֗וֹב) is to ask God : [1] why bad things happen to righteous people, [2] why God allows believers (righteous people) to doubt Him.

In **Job 12:20** we read Iyov's frustration towards God for allowing righteous people the ability to still doubt how He works.

**Iyov 12:20**

> "He removes the speech from trusty men, and takes away the sense of the elders." (מֵסִ֣יר שָׂ֖פָה לְנֶֽאֱמָנִ֑ים וְטַ֖עַם זְקֵנִ֣ים יִקָּֽח)

- This may refer to **Avram ( אַבְרָ֔ם ) in Genesis 15:6-8**. After Avram is declared righteous ( צְדָקָֽה ), he still doubts how YHVH will fulfill His promises asking: "Lord YHVH, how will I know that I will inherit it?" ( אֲדֹנָ֣י יהוה בַּמָּ֥ה אֵדַ֖ע כִּ֥י אִֽירָשֶֽׁנָּה )

**Iyov is frustrated because he believes in YHVH ( יהוה ), he does not completely understand Him.**

Answer (score 1):

There are so many rich treasures in Job, any study has to be careful to note that many different lessons can be drawn, but having said this, I think the salient lesson here is a debate as to who is responsible for Job's sufferings, and in general for all suffering.

Here, Job is responding to Zophar the Naamathite who says that if Job is righteous, then he will be happy and blessed, and if he is sinful, he will stumble. You can think of this as a prosperity Gospel point of view, where we are the ones who control our fate by acting righteously or sinfully, and God is passive always giving good to the righteous and punishing the sinful. God is a type of vending machine that dispenses according to the buttons we press, whether for good or ill.

Then if we encounter someone suffering, we tell them to press different buttons: to repent, or to do some good work, and then their suffering will end and they will get the good snack out of the machine.

Job's position is that God is in charge of everything, both suffering and blessing.

> “But ask the animals, and they will teach you, and the birds of the
> heaven, and they will tell you; or ask the earth, and it will teach
> you, and the fishes of the sea will declare to you. Who among all of
> these does not know that Yahweh’s hand has done this?  *Job 12:7-9 (LEB)*

Moreover Job is turning the table and saying that even those who lack understanding, they do so because God has blinded them. Thus in Job's view God is responsible for all things, both good and bad, and that far from man being able to control outcomes based on his own actions, God is the one controlling all outcomes, even determining whether we make wise choices or poor choices.

Moreover there is another aspect to Job's description of God, which is to say that God is so far higher than we are, that we cannot hope to understand him. The vending machine is too complex for us to operate, and has too much control over our lives, for there to be any recipe we can follow to program the machine and select our outcome.

> Job 12:13–25 (LEB) “With him are wisdom and powerful deeds, and to
> him belong counsel and understanding.
> If he tears down, then it
> will not be rebuilt; if he shuts a man in, then he cannot be freed.
> Look, if he withholds the water, then they dry up; and if he sends
> them out, then they overwhelm the land.  “Strength and sound wisdom
> are with him; the deceived and the deceiver are his.  He leads
> counselors away stripped, and he makes fools of judges.  He loosens
> the fetters of kings, and he binds a loincloth on their loins.  He
> leads priests away stripped, and he overthrows the members of ancient
> families.  He deprives the trustworthy of speech, and he takes away
> the discretion of elders.  He pours contempt on noblemen, and he
> loosens the girdle of the mighty.  “He uncovers mysteries out of
> darkness, and he brings deep shadow to the light.  He makes the
> nations great, then he destroys them; he expands the nations, then he
> guides them.  He strips away the insight of the heads of the earth’s
> people, and he makes them wander in a pathless wasteland.  They
> grope in the dark without light, and he makes them stagger like a
> drunkard.

Answer (score -1):

From God's perspective, Job's remarks weren't scathing. They were ( and are ) true. God makes a point to say ( in Himself as Speech/Word ) that what Job said about God was correct.

Job 42:8  Therefore take unto you now seven bullocks and seven rams, and go to my servant Job, and offer up for yourselves a burnt offering; and my servant Job shall pray for you: for him will I accept: lest I deal with you after your folly, **in that ye have not spoken of me the thing which is right, like my servant Job.**

There is no free will, given that God IS His Word and doesn't "use language". God has said of Himself:

Isaiah 45:7  I form the light, and create darkness: I make peace, **and create evil**: I the LORD do all these things.

with Strong's numbers:

Isaiah  45:7  I formH3335 the light,H216 and createH1254 darkness:H2822 I makeH6213 peace,H7965 and createH1254 evil:H7451 IH589 the LORDH3068 doH6213 allH3605 theseH428 things.

evil:H7451: ( from Strong's) ra`, rah; from 7489; bad or (as noun) evil (natural or moral): — adversity, affliction, bad, calamity, + displease(-ure), distress, evil((- favouredness), man, thing), + exceedingly, X great, grief(-vous), harm, heavy, hurt(-ful), ill (favoured), + mark, mischief(-vous), misery, naught(-ty), noisome, + not please, sad(ly), sore, sorrow, trouble, vex, wicked(-ly, -ness, one), worse(-st), wretchedness, wrong. (Incl. feminine raaah; as adjective or noun.). ( moral evil as well, not just calamity ..note mine )

Source: https://bible.knowing-jesus.com/strongs/H7451

Two things are happening:

1. pre-Incarnate Christ/God was in Job as Job's speech ( as opposed to the non-creating/dragon speech that is now human speech in his three friends and Elihu ) defending him and being honest about God. No one else can know those things about God and God explicitly says that through Paul:

1 Corinthians 2:12-16  Now we have received, not the spirit of the world, but the spirit which is of God; that we might know the things that are freely given to us of God.  Which things also we speak, not in the words which man's wisdom teacheth, but which the Holy Ghost teacheth; comparing spiritual things with spiritual.  **But the natural man receiveth not the things of the Spirit of God: for they are foolishness unto him: neither can he know them, because they are spiritually discerned.**  But he that is spiritual judgeth all things, yet he himself is judged of no man.  For who hath known the mind of the Lord, that he may instruct him? But we have the mind of Christ.

Satan was in Elihu and accused Job of saying evil things about God when in fact God was speaking of Himself through Job ..but I suspect without Job knowing it. Job repented because he recognized the Spirit that spoke through him in God, but was about to take credit for just being that wise on his own simply to keep in solidarity with his version of the human race.

The whole play was God proving ( again) to Satan ( the accuser of our brethren and that accusation in a speech not-God ..anti-Christ) that He was going to save His people no matter what Satan could do and by the means of Himself as Word/Speech of God. With the rise of the so-called "gospel offer", which is basically a human speech/dragon speech mimic of the gospel, but powerless and so has to say free will exists and you have to "choose" ..essentially what is being claimed is that God, Satan and Man all have the same speech and in order to get to God we must go through human speech and get its permission first.

The Incarnation of the Word/Speech of God shows all that up to be flat out lies. Not "good people" with "bad theology". Not a mistake. Not children playing with weapons they don't understand the destructive power of. Just lies. They are lies because there are two speaks in total reality, not one and those lies constantly imply that there is only one universal speech that just happens to not be able to create anything and so must put off the demonstration of any power on the hearer with the widget of the lie of free will of man. Anti-Christ starts out his lie of free will with "you've got all this power!" and ends with "..and so you keep using your free will the wrong way! It's all your fault! Guilty!"

God did not allow Job to speak for himself, yet let him think that was exactly what he had to do given the situation and the whole thing plays out between the pre-Incarnate Word of God and Anti-Christ.

Job's three friends object to the wisdom pre-Incarnate Christ is laying down exactly like free willer preachers and priests. In their view, God owes you something if you do the right thing, and takes vengeance if you don't. They are indignant that their speech is worthless to what God is saying through Job that anti-Christ cannot comprehend.

Job 20:1-3  And Zophar the Naamathite answered and said,  Therefore do my thoughts give me an answer, and for this is my haste within me.  I hear a reproof putting me to shame; and my spirit answereth me by mine understanding.

Zophar here claims his wisdom is the equal of God's and so he presumes to speak on God's behalf never suspecting that his speech is anti-Christ. If he doesn't answer, he already sees his wisdom is put to shame by Job's speech who is Pre-Incarnate Christ. All Job knows about himself and own speech is that he "has to speak".

Anti-Christ through Bildad, objecting to the powerlessness of his own wisdom:

Job 18:1  And Bildad the Shuhite answered and said,  How long will ye hunt for words? Be intelligent, and then we will speak.  Wherefore are we counted as beasts, and reputed stupid in your sight?

Keep in mind that in the end, again, God shows up and explicitly Says that what Job had said of God was right.

It's just God's way. It's not "God's way or leave." You can't leave.

hope this helps.

Isa 26:11-14  Jehovah, thy hand is lifted up, but they do not see: yet they shall see thy jealousy for the people, and be ashamed; yea, the fire which is for thine adversaries shall devour them.  Jehovah, thou wilt ordain peace for us; for thou also hast wrought all our works for us.  Jehovah our God, other lords than thee have had dominion over us; by thee only will we make mention of thy name.   They are dead, they shall not live; deceased, they shall not rise: for thou hast visited and destroyed them, and made all memory of them to perish.

In the Name of Jesus Christ, Amen

Comment: (-1) Hi Tim, I've downvoted this answer as it does not provide any hermeneutical basis for its conclusion, and seems to base its justification on theology you've derived from other passages. To get more familiar with the site's principles, I'd suggest checking out ['What Topics can I ask about here?'](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and ['What are we looking for in answers?'](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/533/13311)